# AChartEngine chart lose auto following after first touch

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I'm currently using AChartEngine library to dinamically draw my sensor data. It's working fine and when i receive  new data the chart scroll and update Y axis values correctly.
The problem is when i touch the chart to manually zoom, move or anything else: the chart loses his "auto following" intelligence and also the "center chart" button in the zoom controls does not center correctly entire chart (but it focus on "old data", before my first touch).

How can i solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you change the visible area manually, it no longer updates it manually. You could probably disable zoom and pan if you want to keep the update feature.

```
renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
```

Comment: It may work if you call renderer.initAxesRangeForScale(0) when you receive new data.

Comment: Works perfect! You save me!

Comment: Also need to call renderer.setYTitle(".."); after initAxesRangeForScale, otherwise the Y label will disappear